# Find the overlapping numbers between two given lists and then print them into a new list only if the new list has the maximum length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, max

> **Problem** :
>
> Given two lists   a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
>
> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
>
> Print a new list of overlapping numbers
>
> (Print Only if the new list has **the maximum lenght**)
>
> (and **be general** if the two initial lists are changed)

**Main Code** : (Printing all the possible cases)

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

listcommonab = []

for numA in a:
    if numA in b: 
        listcommonab.append(numA)
        print(listcommonab)
    else: 
        print(" ")
```

**Result** :

```
    [1]

    [1, 1]

    [1, 1, 2]

    [1, 1, 2, 3]

    [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]

    [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]

    [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

**Attempt #1**

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

listcommonab = []

i = 0

for numA in a: 

listcommonab.append(numA)

i = i+1

if numA in b and i == 7: 
   print(listcommonab)
else: 
    print(" ")
```

**Result Attempt#1**

```
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

It does print the expected output,but this code isn't general enough , because I still have to check if i == 7 to print the expected list.

Any idea to make this code more general and can be applied if **the two initial lists** are changed 
**(i is unknown)** ?

Comment: Just don't print until your loops are both complete, then the list will be as long as it will get. Or just use a list comprehension: `print([v for v in a if v in b])`

Comment: how do you define overlapping?

Comment: Question1: Should the `1` really be added twice? Question2: How do you determine the maximum length?

Comment: @furcifer "exists in both lists"

Comment: is it 1-to1 or will be considered if anywhere exists? give some sample outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sets intersection (if you want only the unique values):

```
res = set(list_a).intersection(set(list_b))
print(list(res))
```